# How do I define a vector of vectors of different types using a variadic template?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, c++17

I would like to make a vector of vectors of different types. Suppose I have 4 classes; Dog, Cat, Pig, Cow. I would like a vector that contains vectors of each of these, and be able to access them by two indices so I can iterate over them, which would be the case if it was a vector of vectors.

I have been toying with things like:

```
std::vector<std::variant<std::vector<Dog>,
    std::vector<Cat>,
    std::vector<Pig>,
    std::vector<Cow>>>;
```

Furthermore, I'd like to be able to construct these arrays with a variadic template construct, so I could easily make another vector of vectors of, say, Apple, Pear, Orange, Lemon, Grape, Cherry.

I would like to be able to write in my code something like:

```
MyVectorOfVectors<Dog,Cat,Pig,Cow> animals;
MyVectorOfVectors<Apple, Pear, Orange, Lemon, Grape, Cherry> fruits;
```

and have that make vectors for each type and store these vectors in another vector (or similar) that I can access by index. Obviously this vector would need to be some sort of heterogeneous container as suggested above with the vector of variants. I would imagine that this would have to be wrapped in some sort of variadic template class definition.

So accessing the third Dog in the array would need a functionality something like this

```
Dog mydog = animals[0][3];
```

or if the solution had to be wrapped in a class,

```
Dog mydog = animals.thearray[0][3];
```

I realise that this could be implemented using a class hierarchy, dynamic allocation, and pointers to objects, but I am looking for a solution with a flat memory model for performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename... T>
using MyVectorOfVectors = std::tuple<std::vector<T>...>;

MyVectorOfVectors<Dog,Cat,Pig,Cow> animals;
MyVectorOfVectors<Apple, Pear, Orange, Lemon, Grape, Cherry> fruits;

void foo()
{
    std::vector<Dog>& dogs = std::get<0>(animals);
    std::vector<Orange>& oranges = std::get<2>(fruits);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/CikWUV)

You have to decide: Either you can deduce types at compile-time (in which case your indices into `MyVectorOfVectors` must also be known at compile time) - then you get all the type safety (as above).

If your indices can also be run-time values, then you need a form of type erasure. That will come with the runtime overhead that you said you'd like to avoid.

In any case, you won't get `Dog dog = animals[0][3]` because the parameter of `operator[]` for whatever `MyVectorOfVectors` ends up being isn't necessarily known at compile-time (from the perspective of the compiler at least).

Comment: This looks promising. Do you know of a way to iterate over the types? I can't use a for loop of course, because the iterator would be runtime. Can you suggest a way of writing one bit of code that would iterate over the types for both animals and fruits?

Comment: You'd probably employ a templated traversal function, similar to how [visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) works with variants.

Comment: I'm marking this as a solution because I've used this construct. It doesn't solve the iteration problem, but I've got some code working to do that also. (See below).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions. I have used Max Langhof's answer to produce the data structure and figured out a method of doing the iteration.

Here's the code I ended up with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include <limits>

template<typename... Ts>
using TupleVector = std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>;

constexpr std::size_t size_t_max = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();

template<typename T, std::size_t N = size_t_max, typename FuncT>
void for_all(T b, FuncT F)
{
  constexpr std::size_t TupSize = std::tuple_size<T>::value;

  // Entry point: No 'N' given - default value.
  if constexpr (N == size_t_max) 
  {
    for_all<T,TupSize-1>(b,F); // So call again with tuple size - 1
  }
  else
  {
    // Actually do it. Loop through vector and call lambda, 
    for (auto &i : std::get<TupSize-N-1>(b))
    {
      F(i);
    }
    // If N == 0 escape, otherwise recurse.
    if constexpr (N > 0) 
    {
      for_all<T,N-1>(b,F); // Recursively call with N - 1
    }
  }
}

struct Dog { int age;  };
struct Cat { int age;  };
struct Pig { int age;  };
struct Cow { int age;  };

int main()
{
  using farmvec = TupleVector<Dog, Cat, Pig, Cow>;
  farmvec animals;
  std::get<0>(animals).push_back(Dog());
  std::get<0>(animals)[0].age=1;
  std::get<0>(animals).push_back(Dog());
  std::get<0>(animals)[1].age=5;

  std::get<1>(animals).push_back(Cat());
  std::get<1>(animals)[0].age=2;

  std::get<2>(animals).push_back(Pig());
  std::get<2>(animals)[0].age=3;

  std::get<3>(animals).push_back(Cow());
  std::get<3>(animals)[0].age=4;

  for_all<farmvec>(animals,[](auto a)
            {
              std::cout << "Age: " << a.age << std::endl;
            });
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it works with non-hierarchical classes using type inference, so there is no need for my Dog, Cat etc. to derive from a base class.

A next step is to be able to use parameters with the lambda, but at least I've got this far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you need, for me it is strange requriement:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
using MatrixVariantRows = std::vector<std::variant<std::vector<Ts>...>>;
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/Jl9j29TgyaXKZAvh

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, here is another possibility. The trade off is that from the compilers perspective you can mix animals or fruits (but not animals and fruits), but the variant ensures at runtime you cannot access the incorrect type.

```
struct Dog {};
struct Cat {};
struct Pig {};
struct Cow {};
struct Apple {};
struct Pear {};
struct Orange {};
struct Lemon {};
struct Grape {};
struct Cherry {};

template<typename... Ts>
using MetaVector = std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<Ts...>>>;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Dog daisy, sadie, molly;
    Cat sam, coco, tiger;
    Pig frankie, albert, digger;

    MetaVector<Dog,Cat,Pig,Cow> animals = {{ daisy, sadie, molly },
                                           { sam, coco, tiger },
                                           { frankie, albert, digger }};
    auto dog0 = std::get<Dog>(animals[0][0]);
    auto dog1 = std::get<Dog>(animals[0][1]);
    auto dog2 = std::get<Dog>(animals[0][2]);

    auto cat0 = std::get<Cat>(animals[0][0]); // throws exception

    MetaVector<Apple,Pear,Orange,Lemon,Grape,Cherry> fruits;

    return 0;
}
```